# Go embedded struct call child method instead parent method

Tags: methods, struct, go, parent-child

Here a sample of Go code with an Interface, a Parent Struct and 2 Children Structs

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

// Shape Interface : defines methods
type ShapeInterface interface {
    Area() float64
    GetName() string
    PrintArea()
}

// Shape Struct : standard shape with an area equal to 0.0
type Shape struct {
    name string
}

func (s *Shape) Area() float64 {
    return 0.0
}

func (s *Shape) GetName() string {
    return s.name
}

func (s *Shape) PrintArea() {
    fmt.Printf("%s : Area %v\r\n", s.name, s.Area())
}

// Rectangle Struct : redefine area method
type Rectangle struct {
    Shape
    w, h float64
}

func (r *Rectangle) Area() float64 {
    return r.w * r.h
}

// Circle Struct : redefine Area and PrintArea method 
type Circle struct {
    Shape
    r float64
}

func (c *Circle) Area() float64 {
    return c.r * c.r * math.Pi
}

func (c *Circle) PrintArea() {
    fmt.Printf("%s : Area %v\r\n", c.GetName(), c.Area())
}

// Genreric PrintArea with Interface
func  PrintArea (s ShapeInterface){
    fmt.Printf("Interface => %s : Area %v\r\n", s.GetName(), s.Area())
}

//Main Instruction : 3 Shapes of each type
//Store them in a Slice of ShapeInterface
//Print for each the area with the call of the 2 methods
func main() {

    s := Shape{name: "Shape1"}
    c := Circle{Shape: Shape{name: "Circle1"}, r: 10}
    r := Rectangle{Shape: Shape{name: "Rectangle1"}, w: 5, h: 4}

    listshape := []c{&s, &c, &r}

    for _, si := range listshape {
        si.PrintArea() //!! Problem is Witch Area method is called !! 
        PrintArea(si)
    }

}
```

I have for results :

```
$ go run essai_interface_struct.go
Shape1 : Area 0
Interface => Shape1 : Area 0
Circle1 : Area 314.1592653589793
Interface => Circle1 : Area 314.1592653589793
Rectangle1 : Area 0
Interface => Rectangle1 : Area 20
```

My problem is the call of `Shape.PrintArea` which call `Shape.Area` method for Circle and Rectangle instead calling `Circle.Area` and `Rectangle.Area` method.

Is this a bug in Go ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually in your example calling `ShapeInterface.PrintArea()` works just fine in case of a `Circle` because you created a `PrintArea()` method for the type `Circle`. Since you did not create a `PrintArea()` for the `Rectangle` type, the method of the embedded `Shape` type will be called.

This is not a bug, this is the intended working. Go is [not (quite) an object oriented language](http://golang.org/doc/faq#Is_Go_an_object-oriented_language): it does not have classes and it [does not have type inheritance](http://golang.org/doc/faq#inheritance); but it supports a similar construct called *embedding* both on `struct` level and on `interface` level, and it does have [methods](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_declarations).

What you expect is called [*virtual methods*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function): you expect that the `PrintArea()` method will call the "overridden" `Area()` method, but in Go there is no inheritance and virtual methods.

The definition of `Shape.PrintArea()` is to call `Shape.Area()` and this is what happens. `Shape` does not know about which struct it is and if it is embedded in, so it can't "dispatch" the method call to a virtual, run-time method.

The [Go Language Specification: Selectors](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Selectors) describe the exact rules which are followed when evaluating an `x.f` expression (where `f` may be a method) to choose which method will be called in the end. Key Points:

> - A selector `f` may denote a field or method `f` of a type `T`, or it may refer to a field or method `f` of a nested [anonymous field](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types) of `T`. The number of anonymous fields traversed to reach `f` is called its *depth* in `T`.
> - For a value `x` of type `T` or `*T` where `T` is not a pointer or interface type, `x.f` denotes the field or method at the shallowest depth in `T` where there is such an `f`.

### Going into details

#### Circle

In case of `Circle`: `si.PrintArea()` will call `Circle.PrintArea()` because you created such a method:

```
func (c *Circle) PrintArea() {
    fmt.Printf("%s : Area %v\r\n", c.GetName(), c.Area())
}
```

In this method `c.Area()` is called where `c` is a `*Circle`, so the method with `*Circle` receiver will be called which also exists.

`PrintArea(si)` calls `si.Area()`. Since `si` is a `Circle` and there is a method `Area()` with `Circle` receiver, it is invoked no problem.

#### Rectangle

In case of `Rectangle` `si.PrintArea()` will actually call the method `Shape.PrintArea()` because you **did not** define a `PrintArea()` method for the `Rectangle` type (there is no method with receiver `*Rectangle`). And the implementation of `Shape.PrintArea()` method calls `Shape.Area()` **not** `Rectangle.Area()` - as discussed, `Shape` doesn't know about `Rectangle`. So you'll see

```
Rectangle1 : Area 0
```

printed instead of the expected `Rectangle1 : Area 20`.

But if you call `PrintArea(si)` (passing the `Rectangle`), it calls `si.Area()` which will be `Rectangle.Area()` because such method exists.

Comment: Further to this, in real code if you wanted/need something like your `func (s *Shape) PrintArea()` you'd just turn it into `func ShapeArea(s ShapeInterface)`; a function that operated on any shape like thing (anything that provided the appropriate methods, e.g. `Area() float64`). Also, in real code it's not a good idea to call functions "PrintFoo" and output to stdout, instead take an `io.Writer` *or* return a `string`. And so-called "getters" usually don't include "Get" in idiomatic Go code; i.e. `Name() string` instead of `GetName() string`.

Answer (score -1):

Go's syntactic sugar for embedding is misleading by design.

For example the following code does not print "Child", it prints "Parent":

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Hello interface {
    Hello()
}

type Parent struct{}

func (this Parent) Hello() {
    fmt.Printf("%T\n", this)
}

type Child struct {
    Parent
}

func main() {
    Child{}.Hello()
}
```

The code `Child{}.Hello()` looks as if the receiver of `Hello` is a `Child`. But that is not the case! Instead it is a `Parent`.